# jScrollPane in jqModal window only works the first time

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jqmodal

i am trying to add the [jScrollPane plugin](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) to my [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) window so that when i load content (via AJAX) that's taller than my set height (600px) the scroll pane can do it's work. the problem is the expected results only occur the first time. each subsequent request to the TEST link loads the data in the jqModal window but the jScrollPane doens't get loaded, but there's no error or warning that something went wrong. so....here's some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/css/jqmodal.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqmodal.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mwheelIntent.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('document').ready(function() {
                var myShow = function(hash){ hash.w.fadeIn('2000',function(){ hash.o.show(); }); };
                var myHide = function(hash){ hash.w.fadeOut('2000',function(){ hash.o.remove(); $('#loading').show(); }); };
                var myLoad = function(){ $('#loading').hide(); $('#window_content').jScrollPane({showArrows: true}); };
                $('#window').jqm({
                    modal: false,
                    trigger: '.link',
                    target: '#window_content',
                    ajax: '@href',
                    onShow: myShow,
                    onHide: myHide,
                    onLoad: myLoad
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="window" class="jqmWindow">
            <a href="#" class="jqmClose">Close</a>
            <div id="loading">Loading...</div>
            <div id="window_content"></div>
        </div>
        <a class="link" href="test.php">TEST</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

And test.php merely consits of:

```
<div>This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data. This is some test data.</div>
```

help me users of stackoverflow. you're my only hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah Hah! Had I only found the documentation sooner I wouldn't have had to post. For those who may have experienced something similar. READ THE DOCS FIRST! lol But for this instance, here's the solution. In the **myHide** function I just had to add:

```
$('#window_content').jScrollPane().data().jsp.destroy();
```

So that it's reinitialized on subsequent calls properly. Thanks again ME! You're welcome me, but again... READ THE DOCS FIRST! :P ([Docs | Destroy](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/destroy.html))